# Mule log4j: Writing a different log file for each payload being processed

Tags: java, logging, log4j, mule

I would like logs to be written to a single file for the current payload in my app, along with having a big log file for all the times my app flow is executed.

For instance is the payload unique identifier was xyz, for mule to create the file:
/mule-dir/logs/xyz.log

I understand I can modify /mule-dir/conf/log4j.properties
But I do not know how to write a pattern that would have access to Mule-specific variables.

Thanks,

Comment: can you use this [(link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324053/configure-log4j-to-log-to-custom-file-at-runtime) ?

Comment: It's not telling how to use a variable only available within the context of Mule, does it?

Comment: You're right, excuse me, I didn't pay much attention to the 'Mule' part of your question. I am no Mule expert but I wonder if you could write a custom `Appender` that using that Mule context and with the idea in the link I posted earlier you could achieve your goal. If nobody answers and I get some time I'll research a bit more. Sorry again.