# log4j trying to log in the file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to use log4j to log it in the file
here's the code

```
    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Application.class);
    private static final String DIRECTORY = "/Users/me/Desktop";
    private static final String EXTENSION = ".log";

    protected void setupLogger(String fileName) {
        SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();
        FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout, DIRECTORY + "/logs/" + fileName + EXTENSION, false);
        logger.addAppender(appender);
        logger.setLevel((Level) Level.DEBUG);
    }
```

and here's the pom that i use http://pastebin.com/vXdFtzSU

The stacktrace that I am getting is here

```
Error:(40, 28) java: incompatible types: org.apache.log4j.FileAppender cannot be converted to org.apache.log4j.Appender
```

I am trying to follow this answer [configure log4j to log to custom file at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324053/configure-log4j-to-log-to-custom-file-at-runtime)

Comment: can you show your import statement

Comment: import org.apache.log4j.Level;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout;
    import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;

Comment: Try to find out dependency tree from below command mvn dependency:tree , and post it here. There is a version conflict of log4j jars.i think you need to exclude log4j from other artifact dependency.

Comment: I am also using spring and thymeleaf. here's my full pom http://pastebin.com/vXdFtzSU

Comment: Spring dependency uses log4j internally . Run mvn dependency:tree command and share.

Comment: @AadityaRaj yeah, I just noticed that now. here's my dependency tree http://pastebin.com/6wJQBDHT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try changin your maven dependencies add this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

and change spring boot dependencies to exclude logging dependencies :

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

then add try/catch statement :

```
    protected void setupLogger(String fileName) {

        try {
            SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();
            FileAppender appender;
            appender = new FileAppender(layout, DIRECTORY + "/logs/" +        fileName + EXTENSION, false); 
            logger.addAppender(appender);
            logger.setLevel((Level) Level.DEBUG);
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now the file is saving on the path that I specified but I am getting stacktrace from setFile http://pastebin.com/FZ6nmTeY

Comment: check if the log file existe in the specified path "/users/me/Desktop/logs/filename.log" or try to use the absolute path ex : "C:/Users/me/logs/filename.log"

Comment: i'm using mac and i did try to use the absolute path

Comment: It's only a matter of path, just check if is right, check also the permission, check if the path already existe. can you post the full path of your log file !!

Answer (score 0):

It almost looks like you are using a different version of the libraray at runtime than at compile-time. If the types were truly incompatible that would generate a compiler error. If you are running your program in a special environment like Tomcat etc. check if the same version of log4j is installed there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use log4j.properties It's a very simple configuration print to file.

```
log4j.logger.register=INFO,R7
log4j.appender.R7=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R7.DatePattern='.'yyyyMMdd
log4j.appender.R7.File=/appLogs/address/logFile.log
log4j.appender.R7.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R7.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} | %m%n


private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("register");

logger.info("print to file and console");
```

Comment: I already tried that but it is not reading my properties. here's the properties http://pastebin.com/Y8JKCuTY maybe because of spring